# Java: BufferedWriter skipping newline

Tags: java

I am using the following function to write a string to a File. The string is formatted with newline characters.

For example, `text = "sometext\nsomemoretext\nlastword";`

I am able to see the newline characters of the output file when I do:

```
type outputfile.txt
```

However, when I open the text in notepad I can't see the newlines. Everything shows up in a single line.

Why does this happen. How can I make sure that I write the text properly to be able to see correctly (formatted) in notepad.

```
    private static void FlushText(String text, File file)
    {
        Writer writer = null;
        try
        {          
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            writer.write(text);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (writer != null)
                {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On windows, new-lines are represented, by convention, as a carriage-return followed by a line-feed (CR + LF), i.e. `\r\n`.

From the [Newline wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

> Text editors are often used for
>   converting a text file between
>   different newline formats; most modern
>   editors can read and write files using
>   at least the different ASCII CR/LF
>   conventions. **The standard Windows
>   editor Notepad is not one of them**
>   (although Wordpad is).

Notepad should display the output correctly if you change the string to:

```
text = "sometext\r\nsomemoretext\r\nlastword";
```

If you want a platform-independent way of representing a new-line, use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` For the specific case of a `BufferedWriter`, go with what bemace suggests.

Comment: Oh. Now I am using System.getProperty("line.separator"); Can't use BufferedWriter.newLine() as I need to populate the complete string before writing it.

Comment: This saved me. I am working with Wicket, and BufferedWriter.newLine() worked locally, but not on tomcat.. I tried the \r\n and it worked like a charm.. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is why you should use `BufferedWriter.newLine()` instead of hardcoding your line separators.  It will take care of picking the correct version for whatever platform you're currently working on.