# BufferedWriter.newLine() is not working in Android

Tags: java, android

I dont know why it is happening.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("mnt/sdcard/Menu.ini"));
for (int i = 0; i < AppItem.length; i++) {      
    writer.write(AppItem[i]);
    writer.newLine();
}
writer.close();
```

In Java it is working perfectly. When I am doing in Android, created file (menu.ini) is not accepting the `newLine();`. I have tried `"\n"` and `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in place of `writer.newLine();`
**The problem is, all string coming in one line and the rectangular boxes are coming where the line is being end.**

Any solution or **any alternative way where I can write my string array to a file.**
Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing the rectangular boxes? Txt editor?

Comment: @KenWolf on system's NotePad

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4066962/833647 Try changing to `\r\n`

Comment: @KenWolf i just tried that, Now new Lines are coming but the end of every line I can see three rectangular boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedWriter.newline()` will use a platform-specific seperator.

> A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property `line.separator`. Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines. Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore preferred to writing a newline character directly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

But my understanding is you are looking at the file on Windows, in Notepad, which does not recognise it the seperator as it was created on a different platform.

So your code is fine, but your test is wrong :)

If your goal is to see it in Notepad, change the line seperator to `\r\n`

Comment: Actually my goal does not end here. This file I have to read again and while reading it is giving problem

Comment: I think I've helped answer your question about why you were not seeing line breaks in NotePad - it was down to platform-specific line seperator used. If you are having further problems I advise you to open up a new question, alternatively maybe someone else will help.