# Write Strings that contain \n with BufferedWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

If I have a String that contains some words with here and there a \n in between, 
is there a way to write them into a .txt file on separate lines? For example:

```
    File myFile = new File("TextFile.txt");
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(myFile.getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    try {
        bw.write(myString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where myString is something like:

```
"\nwords\nwords\nwords\n"
```

With this code I get in the text file `words words words` instead of

```
words 
words
words
```

Comment: I tried your code and get the final result you posted (three "words" in separated lines). Is this the result you want?

Comment: If you use windows editor have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066958/java-bufferedwriter-skipping-newline on windows editor you need \r\n instead \n

Comment: Yes I would like 3 separated lines with on each line "words". Did you use the .write() of BufferedWriter? Because when I use it in my program it writes everything on one line in my file?

Comment: Yes, I used exactly your code (just add a line: `String myString = "\nwords\nwords\nwords\n"`. If you are using Windows, maybe the method mentioned by @pL4Gu33 worth a try (I am not using Windows currently).

Comment: Problem fixed! It was indeed the \r\n that was needed because I use Windows. Could you explain me why and what the difference is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use an editor which understands `\n` as newline, or use this code:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\n","\r\n");
```

Comment: Or you could always just use "\r\n" in the String/StringBuilder object if you're able to.