# BufferedWriter class writeLine method

Tags: java

Why does the `BufferedReader` class have a `readLine()` method, but the `BufferedWriter` class doesn't have a `writeLine(String)` method? Now we have to do `write(str + "\n")` or `write(str)` and `newLine()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reading through javadocs I do not see any specific reason why a `writeLine()` method is not provided. With the provided `write` methods BufferedWriter will buffer the characters before writing for efficiency purposes. Providing a new `writeLine()` method will not add any value since the character stream provided in this imaginary `writeLine` method will be buffered and written only when the buffer is full.

You can switch to [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class instead of BufferedWriter as it provides `println(String str)` method which can be used write a string and a newline character. But this is inefficient when compared to BufferedWriter and it is better to use this only when you want your output file to have the strings written immediately on calling the println() method.

With `BufferedWriter` class for the reason mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066958/java-bufferedwriter-skipping-newline) best approach is to use `write()` and `newLine()` methods.

To leverage the benefits of `BufferedWriter` and to have access to `println()` method, you can do the below as suggested in [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
out.println("Hello World!");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I know I have to do that, but I was just wondering why there is no convenience method for doing it in one call. Other languages I know like C# do have that.

Comment: @0ne_Up - I looked up and could not find a writeLine() equivalent in BufferedStream class of C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream_methods(v=vs.90).aspx. Can you let me know which class you are referring to ?

Comment: StreamWriter, PrintWriter for example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: But I didn't know about `PrintWriter` in java, thanks for explaining.
But why would `BufferedWriter.writeLine()` not add value? If it is written when the buffer is full, or when the `flush` method is called you would still have to call fewer methods.

Comment: @0ne_Up - I don't have answer for why BufferedWriter class was originally designed to not have writeLine() method. But I updated my answer on how to write new lines with fewer calls without compromising on efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. It wouldn't be less efficient if the `autoFlush` flag is set to false. But I still don't get why there are so many different classes (`BufferedWriter`, `PrintWriter`, `FileWriter`, `OutputStreamWriter`, `OutputStream`) and what exactly the difference is between the `write` and `print` methods. In C# you can just do `new StreamWriter("foo.bar")`.

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

> A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator. Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines. Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore preferred to writing a newline character directly.